Is there a way to force a command's argument to read from stdin instead of straight from the command line?
I have a python script I'm running that I don't have the ability to change. Here's how I tried running it:
python my_script.py --username <username> --password -

Just to see if python would allow me to use the - to read from stdin somehow, but it didn't, the script just assumed the password I wanted was "-" of course.
Can I force the input to --password to be read from stdin somehow?

Try this: python my_script.py --username <username> --password $(head -n1)

Use xargs my_script.py --username <username> --password so xargs will read from STDIN and pass the value as argument.

if you use argparse, you could define the --password argument as a flag with parser.add_argument("--password", action="store_true") and then call getpass.getpass() in your script if the --password flag is given

@LéaGris Try this: echo -n Enter password:\ ;echo Password is: $(sed 1q) ( under sh too ;-)

Do this answer your question: Bash- passing input without shell interpreting parameter expansion chars

To at least provide some hint to the user that password is required, you can do something like this
stty -echo; read -rp 'Password: ' p; stty echo; python my_script.py --username <username> --password "$p"

